# Sqoop MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY columns in GCP DataProc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sqoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to sqoop MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column into GCS Bucket using dataproc but sqoop is ignoring MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY column from selection. I am not sure what is the issue. Also Do I need to convert it using map-column-java?

I tried to convert it to String using map column java but it says column not found means sqoop is ignoring that column from selection